# I'm looking for a cross platform offline AI photo organiser

Tags: offline, photography, cross-platform, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for a software like [PhotoPrism](https://www.photoprism.app/),
But I don't want to host it on a machine permanently.
I can host it temporarily on machine so that it saves all tags(by tags I mean face and text data that describe the image.) with photos on a external drive. Then I can install the software to view by those tags on my devices.
Then I'll connect my external drive to my PC or Phone and view the sorted photos by that software.

If you know a way to do it with PhotoPrism or you know any other software that could help me then please tell me.

My condition :-

- My external drive is a fast SSD that could handle heavy tasks.
- The software should AI sort by text in photos , faces , scenes ,etc.
- I'll add photos in months and don't need regular scanning or tagging.
- The software should work smooth on Android and Windows
- I can't buy a server or connect my PC to internet due to privacy

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you expect software to tag the photos?